# Jquery selects and inputs texts

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<form ...>
<select name="fuits[]" id="fruits[]">
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="O">Orange</option>
    <option value="P">Pear</option>   
</select>
<input type="text" name="fruit[]" id="fruit[]" />

<select name="fruits[]" id="fruits[]">
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="O">Orange</option>
    <option value="P">Pear</option>   
</select>
<input type="text" name="fruit[]" id="fruit[]" />

<select name="fruits[]" id="fruits[]">
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="O">Orange</option>
    <option value="P">Pear</option>   
</select>
<input type="text" name="fruit[]" id="fruit[]" />

...

<input type="submit" value="send" />
```

So, I need fill each input text from each select option values (match input text with the selected option)

I have this JQuery, but it doesn't work fine =(,

```
$("select[name='type[]']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='tvalue[]']").eq($(this).index()).val(this.value);
}).change();
```

Here is the DEMO (thanks to karim79): http://jsfiddle.net/GKrd9/4/
suggestions please?

Thanks!
Carlos

Answer (score 3):

I'v edited your fiddle, hope this is what you want.

```
$("select[name='type[]']").change(function() {
    $(this).next().val(this.value);
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GKrd9/5/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing missing in your code is a selector in [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

This fixes your problem :

```
$("select[name='type[]']").change(function() {
    $("input[name='tvalue[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val(this.value);
}).change();
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kreaus/GKrd9/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var jqThis = $(this);
        jqThis
            .next('input')
            .val(jqThis.find('option:selected').val())
    }).change();
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HPYxy/